# How to detect if a location prompt was displayed

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep track of how many users were actually shown a prompt for their location. Is there a way to determine if a location prompt has been (or will be) displayed in the user's browser? On my website, I have a button that will attempt to get the current position of the user. However, this does not always mean that a prompt is displayed since the browser remembers the users choice and current browser settings.

My code looks similar to the following:

```
var onClick = function() {
    //  How do I implement this method?
    var willAppear = geolocationPromptWillAppear();

    if (willAppear) {
        console.log('The prompt is actually going to show');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccessCallback, geoErrorCallback);
}
```

Comment: Can't be done...that functionality is outside of the window context. What is your use case?

Comment: Why does it matter if the prompt is displayed?  Some users may set their preferences to always share their location, others may choose never and their decision has no reflection or relevance specific to your site.  I would just count the number of people who are using geolocation and check the percentage of total visitors against them.

Comment: You can store a flag at `localStorage` within `geoSuccessCallback` function body. Though user could disable geolocation following flag being initially set. The flag would indicate that `geoSuccessCallback` was reached at least once.

Comment: @charlietfl I am trying to track how many users were prompted for their location and how many declined to share that information. I have yet to find a method that does not give skewed results due to browser preferences.

Comment: `geolocationPromptWillAppear` is an external window or a element inside page